# timeout on function and goroutine leak

Tags: go, memory-leaks, timeout

I wish to put a timeout on a function called `foo`. Consider the following

```
func fooWithTimeout(d time.Duration) error {
    ch := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        ch <- foo()
    }()

    select {
    case err := <-ch:
        return err
    case <-time.After(d):
        return errors.New("foo has timed out")
    }
}
```

- If `foo` has timed out, then will `foo` ever be able to write to channel `ch` or is there a risk the goroutine blocks or panics?
- What happens to channel `ch` once `fooWithTimeout` has exited?
- Is this code potentially problematic?
- Should I add `defer close(ch)` within `go func(){...}()` just before calling `foo`?
- Does it matter that I use a buffered (with size 1) or an unbuffered channel in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the timer tick, `fooWithTimeout` will return. The goroutine will continue running until `foo` returns.

If `foo` times out, it will write to channel `ch` because it is buffered.

The channel `ch` will be garbage collected eventually if `foo` returns.

You don't need to close the channel. Once it is out of scope, it will be garbage collected.

A large burst of calls `fooWithTimeout` will create large amount of resources. Each call creates two goroutines. The proper way of timing this out is to change `foo` to use a context.

Answer (score 1):

Building on https://stackoverflow.com/a/73611534/1079543, here is `foo` with a context:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func foo(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
    ch := make(chan string, 1)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("Sleeping...")
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
        fmt.Println("Wake up...")
        ch <- "foo"
    }()

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return "", fmt.Errorf("context cancelled: %w", ctx.Err())
    case result := <-ch:
        return result, nil
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*3)
    defer cancel()

    res, err := foo(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("foo failed: %v", err)
    }

    log.Printf("res: %s", res)
}
```